# TextView gets cut off in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I was looking already at the solutions of similar questions here but they could not solve my problem, so I am writing here.

[image]

This is the picture from the layoutedior. Seems all fine. When I run this app, the lower half of my textview gets cut off and I do not know why.

Maybe you can find something suspicious:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#f4f4f4"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#eadca6"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="342dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="@string/all_quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="342dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="@string/favorite_quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is the resolution of the device that you run the app on the same as the resolution of the device selected for the layout editor? Do you really need a top margin of 260dp for button1?

Comment: It looks like the screen of the device is not high enough: smaller than (144 + 260 + 20 = 424) dp plus the heights of the TextViews ([sp depends on screen resolution as well as user preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237520/whats-the-relationship-between-the-font-size-and-the-height-of-textview-in-andr))

Comment: Just check `android:layout_height="0dp"` by `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `TextView` text size are very large value here `android:textSize="60sp"`
you can change it to samller value and change `TextView` height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your TextView and it would work.
This is not a normal layout, the parent is Constraint Layout, it needs either of the value to work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

1.) Your textview height should be wrap_content (should fix your issue)

2.) you don't need app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500" since your start/left and end/right bounds are already parent which should center your views

3.) you don't need app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0", your view already constrained to the top of parent